# What needs to be defined on a space in order to define area?

Tags: differential-geometry, area, exterior-algebra

I am in physics. I am trying to improve my understanding of differential forms & particularly, here, the wedge product.  I know that the wedge product allows a more general calculation of area, but I realize now that I don't know what area is. Wiki defines area using a Jordan measure, but I don't know any measure theory. I am more than willing to shelve the question of what area is until I learn more measure theory.

However, I am hoping that someone can at least point out the minimum structure which needs to be defined on my set without measure theory. i.e. it would be nice to know what kind of space I could be finding area in.

I would a assume the space needs a metric. I want to say it should have inner product, but I am not sure.

Comment: The most general structure that allows for discussions of "area" is a _measure space_. You can look it up. A metric is not required. Measure spaces are more general than manifolds where area can be defined with wedge products.

Comment: @EthanBolker ok! So, measure space means I can define area and manifold means I can use the wedge product to calculate area? That's very helpful!

Comment: @EthanBolker doesn't a measure space more properly generalize ($n$ dimensional) volume and not just area?

Comment: @CheerfulParsnip Yes. That's why my comment has "area" in quotes. There is no notion of dimension in an arbitrary measure space. The wedge product definition when you have an appropriate manifold is not restricted to two dimensions.

Comment: @EthanBolker I interpreted the question to be about area specifically. Personally I think it's an interesting question whether there is a notion of "area space" akin to "length space."

Comment: @EthanBolker This truly a naïve question, but what kind of structure does the manifold need to have to define the wedge product / what structure does a manifold have. My guess is this might be a nontrivial question since I don't see a obvious answer, but I thought I would ask

Comment: @EricH the manifold needs to have a differential structure, which are sets of local coordinates which are differentiably compatible. See "smooth manifold."